# Retrieve value from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a array formatted as below

```
[
    {
        'id':1,
        'some_int': 3,
        'foo':'bar'
    }
]
```

How can I retrieve, for example, 'bar' value?

If I write

```
$array[0]['bar']
```

It throws **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

If I write

```
$array['bar']
```

It throws **Unidentified index: bar**

Comment: When you do your `json_decode` make sure the second param is set to `true`. This will decode it all as array. Without it, `$array[0]` is and object of type `stdClass` which you'd need to access as `$array[0]->bar` depending on PHP version.

Comment: Short answer: what you have, is not an array. Not in PHP-terms, at least.

Comment: its an json array first convert it into php array by json_encode($json_array) and the get value by foreach loop

Comment: @HassanTahir 1) If you have JSON, you need to json_decode, not encode. 2), going bt the error messages I think we can be confident OP has already decoded.

Comment: sorry i wrote it mistakenly  
its an json array first convert it into php array by json_decode($json_array) and the get value by foreach loop